# Icon Function Not being Ran On Press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using React-Native-Router-Flux for my React-Native app for my routes. In my routes I have a function call on the MoreIcon which should be ran onPress but nothing is executing unless I remove the Lambda operator, but then it executes it immediately on mount of the component.

I've tried to return and not return the alert function being called from the onPress with still no luck.

```
    {/* Live Feed Tab View */}
    <routes.Scene key = "Live" title = "Live" icon={Icons.LiveIcon}>
      <routes.Scene key="LiveFeed" component={LiveFeed} renderRightButton = {() => { return <MoreIcon onPress = { () => {return alert() } }   />; }} renderTitle={() => { return <AppLogo />; }} />
      <routes.Scene  key="Profile" component={Profile} title="Profile" renderRightButton = {() => { return <MoreIcon  />; }} /> 
      <routes.Scene key="Reply" component={Reply} title="Replies" />
      <routes.Scene key="Camera" component={Camera} title="Camera" />
      <routes.Scene key="Preview" component={Preview} title="Preview" />
      <routes.Scene key="MakePost" component={MakePost} title="MakePost" />
    </routes.Scene>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for ```MoreIcon```?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Inside More Icon the onPress is Pass down to an element that can handle touches like TouchableOpacity. Check how in the oficial docs the onPress Function is trigger from the TouchableOpacity Component that wrap around an image. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html